# Graph add_nodes_from() nodes not working, add_edges_from() edges not working properly for data no dependent node/edge DAG is created

Tags: python, graph, networkx

**Problem**

This code is not working to write graph edges and nodes from csv lists and this code is not creating a proper graph from edges sent to add_nodes_from() for nodes and add_edges_from() for edges. So what is the property way to get a graph database to receive and read nodes and edges and even labels to nodes to build a networkx graph database correctly. I have trued many different approaches and none have worked correctly to build a networkx graph. I'm getting no progress on this issue, need to get this done this week.

My code is not capturing nodes and adding edges.

**Code**

```
import networkx as nx
from sknetwork.data import from_edge_list, from_adjacency_list, from_csv

edges = from_csv("real_edges.csv")
nodes = from_csv("real-fnodes.csv")

_nodes = [n for n in nodes]
_edges = [n for n in edges]

G = nx.Graph() 
G.add_nodes_from(_nodes) 
G.add_edges_from(_edges) 
print(nx.info(G))
```

**Data**

Sample Data nodes

```
(0, 1265)   1
  (0, 1338) 1
  (0, 1413) 1
  (0, 1643) 1
  (0, 1719) 1
  (0, 1806) 1
  (0, 2052) 1
  (0, 2128) 1
  (0, 2641) 1
  (0, 2872) 1
  (0, 3100) 1
  (0, 3244) 1
  : :
  (5778, 52)    1
  (5779, 3) 4
  (5780, 3) 4
  (5781, 1) 1
  (5781, 3) 2
  (5781, 29)    1
  (5782, 3) 4
  (5783, 3) 4
  (5784, 3) 4
  (5785, 3) 4
  (5786, 3) 4
  (5787, 3) 4
  (5788, 3) 2
  (5788, 5) 1
  (5788, 47)    1
  (5789, 3) 4
  (5790, 3) 2
  (5790, 5) 1
  (5790, 47)    1
  (5791, 3) 4
  (5792, 3) 2
  (5792, 5) 1
  (5792, 29)    1
```

Sample Nodes Data

```
[['0', '1', '2', '3'], ['5.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['40.0', '13.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['40.0', '13.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['40.0', '13.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '48.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '48.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '11.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '11.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['17.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['1.0', '45.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['1.0', '45.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['1.0', '30.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['1.0', '30.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '29.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '48.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['17.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['17.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['48.0', '44.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['0.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['17.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['40.0', '13.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['17.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['17.0', '52.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['40.0', '13.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['34.0', '54.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '0.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '0.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['40.0', '13.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '1.0', '29.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['1.0', '29.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['1.0', '29.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '52.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '48.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '11.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['0.0', '52.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['1.0', '29.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['1.0', '29.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['40.0', '13.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['40.0', '13.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['40.0', '13.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '52.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '48.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '11.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['48.0', '44.0', '5.0', '47.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['1.0', '29.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['1.0', '29.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['40.0', '13.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '52.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '52.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '52.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '48.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '42.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['21.0', '17.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['3.0', '3.0', '5.0', '3.0'], ['5.0', '47.0', '5.0', '3.0']
```

Sample Data edges

```
(0, 682)    1
  (0, 683)  1
  (0, 755)  1
  (0, 756)  1
  (0, 794)  1
  (0, 807)  1
  (0, 808)  1
  (0, 883)  1
  (0, 884)  1
  (0, 965)  1
  : :
  (5793, 1492)  1
  (5793, 1968)  1
  (5793, 2050)  1
  (5793, 2347)  1
  (5793, 2491)  1
  (5793, 3171)  1
  (5793, 3549)  1
  (5793, 3772)  1
  (5793, 5469)  1
  (5793, 5504)  1
  (5793, 5727)  1
  (5793, 5766)  1
  (5793, 5767)  1
  (5793, 5768)  1
  (5793, 5769)  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is occurring due to the inconsistent nature of the CSV file. You may have to read the CSV file using Python file read, edit the data into a recognizable form and then create a graph.

Assuming the numerical value outside the tuple in the data to be the weight, here is a code that might work:

```
import re
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from sknetwork.data import from_edge_list

# Getting entries of the csv file as python list
with open('real_edges.csv','r') as f:
  edges = f.readlines()

# Extracting the numerical values of each entry and
# saving it as a numpy array
edges = [re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', edge) for edge in edges]
np_edgelist = np.asarray(edges,dtype=int)

# Creating sknetwork graph 
# (matrix_only=True) returns only the adjacency matrix
graph = from_edge_list(np_edgelist, weighted=True, matrix_only=True)

# NetworkX graph from adjacency matrix
g = nx.to_networkx_graph(graph)
```

Comment: for nodes, (5795, 4) is my shape. how would I add these to the graph? I tried with error on the following code: graph = from_adjacency_list(np_nodelist)

Comment: Can you give a sample of your nodes' data? The sample you have given above has only two columns.

Comment: Yes, editing to provide data on nodes. See above, nodes data added

Comment: I don't understand. Is each node a 4-tuple? Is the graph lying in a 4-D space?

Comment: ['5.0', '47.0', '1.0', '29.0'], it's setup as node + weight, e.g., 5.0, 47.0